# Why does maya return a different value than 3ds max?

Tags: python, trigonometry, maya

Why does maya return a different value for cos(1) than 3ds Max? I was trying to make a circle shape and became confused about this topic.

Maya returns:

```
import math
p = math.cos(1.0)
print p
returns: 0.540302305868
```

3ds Max returns:

```
p = cos(1.0)
print p
returns: 0.999848
```

In 3ds Max this returns me a perfect circle. In maya I'm not sure what happens to it...Hopefully it's just something I'm overlooking that's causing this to result in an unexpected behavior.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import math

cmds.file(new=True, f=True)

radius = 10
sides = 8
ang = 360.0 / sides
pts = []


for i in range(0,sides):
    x = radius * math.cos(i * ang )
    y = 0
    z = radius * math.sin(i * ang)
    pt = (x, y, z)
    print i

    pts.append(pt)

cmds.curve(d=1, p=pts )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cos` in 3ds max probably expects degrees. while `math.cos` expect radians

```
In [66]: math.cos(1)
Out[66]: 0.5403023058681397

In [67]: math.cos(math.radians(1)) #Converting 1 degree to radians
Out[67]: 0.9998476951563913
```

Comment: awesome. Thank you. Didn't even think about that prior to this. Great work